# Getting List.Join to compare properly

Tags: c#, list, compare

I am trying to create a list by joining two lists if a property matches correctly. I am using the following command:

```
FooList = TrackedStrings.Join (FooList,
                                str => str,
                                Foo => Foo.GetString (),
                                (str, Foo) => Foo,
                                new Comparer ())
                                .ToList ();
```

And the following class to compare:

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
  public bool Equals (string x, string y)
  {
    return y.Contains (x);
  }

  public int GetHashCode (string str)
  {
    return str.GetHashCode ();
  }
}
```

Now, the idea is that I only want to keep the items that have a GetString () containing any one of the strings from TrackedStrings. However, it doesn't work: the comparer only returns true if the strings are equal. For example, let's say that we have two lists:

```
List<string> TrackedActions = new List<string> { "Created", "Deleted" };
List<Foo> FooList = new List<FooList> { new Foo ("Created"), new Foo ("Deleted Something")};
```

With the current command, the second Foo is dropped from the list - instead of matching to `TrackedActions[1]` and being kept.

Thus, my question is: Why is `Comparer` not working the way I expect it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use IEqualityComparer because `The Equals method is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.equals(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your case its not symmetric `Equals(a,b) != Equals (b,a)`

Glorfindel's answer is not totally correct too, because it's not transitive:

```
Equals("abcd","bc") == true
Equals("bcde", "bc") == true
Equals("abcd","bcde") == false
```

Answer (score 2):

A custom comparer must make sure that the [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.equals(v=vs.110).aspx) relationship it defines is [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry#In_logic). This means that whenever `x.Equals(y)`, `y.Equals(x)` and vice versa.

The reason for this is that you can never predict in which order the elements are compared, i.e. which one of these is called:

```
aStringFromLeftList.Equals(aStringFromRightList)
```

or

```
aStringFromRightList.Equals(aStringFromLeftList)
```

Because the relationship you need is neither symmetric nor transitive, you can't use a Comparer for your problem.

Comment: I see. I guess I will have to find some other way to combine the two lists.

Comment: Hello, your implementation is not transitive, but Equals should be.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparer not working is due to the implementation of the `GetHashCode()`
regardless the **right** way to implement the `IEqualityComparer`.

The match is done by

1. Compare the hashcode of 2 strings. In your case `Deleted Something` definitely return different hashcode with `Deleted`
2. If (1) is equal, then use Equals() to compare again because HashCode may have collision and not accurate, but fast.